# While destructuring array in javascript redeclaration error shown?

Tags: javascript, destructuring

[image]

Same code is run on vs code and i get the values but while checking in browser console. Above error is shown. Please help to solve the query.

Comment: It tells you the `value` variable has already been declared. inspect your code carefully, line by line...

Comment: You are using `const`... your screenshot tells us nothing since we cannot know what code did you run before this. there must have been something which already used that identifier.

Comment: Has nothing to do with the destructuring. The line with the error is not there.

Comment: I dont know if it is already the case, chrome dev tools not allows you to declare a const, execute the code and retry to define the same const and re-execute the code. you should rename the variables each time.

Answer (score 1):

Prior Chrome 92, it was not possible to redeclare the same `const` in the console in different executions.
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-92/#const-redeclaration

I think you could just update your chrome and your code will work (I just tried it) ;)

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: This is not an answer, just a suggestion.

when running code in the browser, please run it inside a function and then call that function. This will help you avoid scope issues which might be the case in your question.

I am adding an example here

```
function test(){
    const value = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    const [a, b, c] = value;
    console.log(a, b, c);
}
test()
```

This is what you should try to follow.
Benefits of following this:

- can be called multiple times without writing the whole code every time
- can pass arguments in the function to make it dynamic